# Wordpress toggle menu is not functioning

Tags: wordpress, menu, toggle, responsive

Currently working on http://getfitquick.co.uk/ but have come into an issue, when the menu is viewed on Tablets/Mobile the menu is currently active with the toggle constantly on, would really like to remove this so that the user is able to click menu and allow the menu to appear as opposed to it always being active.

Would also like to mention for reference that on http://getfitquick.co.uk/shop/ the menu is actually appearing how I want it to, however I am a bit unsure how I did this,

Is there anything anyone could suggest? Maybe something I may have done wrong within the process?

Thanks for reading,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the homepage there's a css code that runs `display: inline-block !important;` for `.menu .nav`

```
@media (max-width: 768px) (index):251 
.menu .nav {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #000000;
    left: 0px;
    border-color: #e51d25;
    display: inline-block !important;
}
```

that code will override the default behavior of the mobile nav
at the top of that code, there's a comment that says

```
/*
    The following CSS generated by Yellow Pencil Plugin.
    http://waspthemes.com/yellow-pencil
*/
```

So I'm not quit sure if that CSS is directly generated from that plugin option on the homepage or if its from a custom CSS code assign to that homepage,

the best way to fix that is to look for that code, its should be somewhere in the Yellow Pencil Plugin

The second option though is really a bad idea is to modify and override it

CSS Override

```
header .menu .nav {
    display: none !important;
}
header .menu.active .nav {
    display: block !important;
}
```

then add `active` when the button is click and remove it when click again,
jQuery

```
(function( $) {
 $('header').on('click', '.menu .toggleMenu', function() {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
 });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response,

I tried to find the code but couldn't find it, but will have another look, so the fix would be to remove the !important class? 

Also as I couldn't find the code, I attempted to Override the CSS, however that ended up hiding the navigation on desktop, is there anyway to have the toggle menu function on mobile, but for desktop still appear?